# Visual Basic / SQL Server: identity_insert is set to off error

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, game-engine

I just recently started toying with all of this programming stuff, so I'm not quite sure on how to fix a minor problem I seem to have with the communication between the server and the client.

when I start up the server, players are able to connect and log out when they are done playing without any problems, but the server throws an error and doesn't save the item in the table `items`.

It's almost as if the server/client can't communicate properly with the `dbo.items` table :/

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

And sorry for the bad English

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace Goose
{
    /**
     * Item, holds the actual item data
     * 
     * Each item in game is separate
     * Holds the original template and modified/added stats
     * 
     */
    public class Item : IItem
    {
        public int ItemID { get; set; }
        public int TemplateID { get; set; }
        public ItemTemplate Template { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public int GraphicEquipped { get; set; }
        public int GraphicTile { get; set; }
        public int GraphicR { get; set; }
        public int GraphicG { get; set; }
        public int GraphicB { get; set; }
        public int GraphicA { get; set; }

        int weapondamage = 0;

        public int WeaponDamage 
        {
            get
            {
                return this.weapondamage + (int)Math.Ceiling(this.Template.WeaponDamage * this.StatMultiplier);
            }
            set
            {
                this.weapondamage = value;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Body pose/state 1 for normal, 3 for staff, 4 for sword
         */
        public int BodyState { get; set; }

        public AttributeSet BaseStats { get; set; }
        public AttributeSet TotalStats { get; set; }

        public decimal StatMultiplier { get; set; }
        /**
         * Dirty, has data changed since loading
         * 
         */
        public bool Dirty { get; set; }
        /**
         * Delete, item is no longer in game so delete it
         */
        public bool Delete { get; set; }
        public long Value { get; set; }

        bool bound = false;
        public bool IsBound
        {
            get { return this.bound; }
            set { this.bound = value; }
        }

        /**
         * These properties are read only and just pass along from the templates properties
         * 
         */
        public int WeaponDelay { get { return this.Template.WeaponDelay; } }
        public int StackSize { get { return this.Template.StackSize; } }
        public bool IsLore { get { return this.Template.IsLore; } }
        public bool IsBindOnPickup { get { return this.Template.IsBindOnPickup; } }
        public bool IsBindOnEquip { get { return this.Template.IsBindOnEquip; } }
        public bool IsEvent { get { return this.Template.IsEvent; } }
        public ItemTemplate.ItemSlots Slot { get { return this.Template.Slot; } }
        public ItemTemplate.ItemTypes Type { get { return this.Template.Type; } }
        public ItemTemplate.UseTypes UseType { get { return this.Template.UseType; } }
        public int MinLevel { get { return this.Template.MinLevel; } }
        public int MaxLevel { get { return this.Template.MaxLevel; } }
        public long MinExperience { get { return this.Template.MinExperience; } }
        public long MaxExperience { get { return this.Template.MaxExperience; } }
        /**
         * This is a bitmask
         * Therefore only limited to about 64 classes, which should be enough.
         * If the bit is set then that class id CAN'T use the item.
         * 
         */
        public long ClassRestrictions { get { return this.Template.ClassRestrictions; } }
        public SpellEffect SpellEffect { get { return this.Template.SpellEffect; } }
        public decimal SpellEffectChance { get { return this.Template.SpellEffectChance; } }
        public int LearnSpellID { get { return this.Template.LearnSpellID; } }

        public bool Unsaved { get; set; }

        public Item()
        {
            this.Unsaved = true;
            this.ItemID = 0;
            this.TotalStats = new AttributeSet();
            this.BaseStats = new AttributeSet();
            this.StatMultiplier = 1;
            this.Dirty = true;
            this.Delete = false;
        }

        /**
         * LoadFromTemplate, loads item from a template
         * 
         * This is when we want an item the same as the template.
         * 
         */
        public void LoadFromTemplate(ItemTemplate template)
        {
            this.Template = template;
            this.TemplateID = this.Template.ID;
            this.TotalStats += this.Template.BaseStats;

            this.Name = this.Template.Name;
            this.Description = this.Template.Description;
            this.GraphicEquipped = this.Template.GraphicEquipped;
            this.GraphicTile = this.Template.GraphicTile;
            this.GraphicR = this.Template.GraphicR;
            this.GraphicG = this.Template.GraphicG;
            this.GraphicB = this.Template.GraphicB;
            this.GraphicA = this.Template.GraphicA;

            this.Value = this.Template.Value;
            this.BodyState = this.Template.BodyState;
        }

        /**
         * LoadTemplate, adds template to item
         * 
         * This is when we want to just add the templates stats to our item
         * ie when loading the items database, eg for surname/titled items
         * 
         * Note: Doesn't load the value from the template as we want to keep the value as 0
         * if the item is custom for example
         * 
         */
        public void LoadTemplate(ItemTemplate template)
        {
            this.TotalStats += template.BaseStats;
            this.TotalStats *= this.StatMultiplier;
            this.TotalStats += this.BaseStats;
        }

        /**
         * AddItem, adds item to database
         * 
         */
        public void AddItem(GameWorld world)
        {
            SqlParameter nameParam = new SqlParameter("@itemName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 64);
            nameParam.Value = this.Name;
            SqlParameter descriptionParam = new SqlParameter("@itemDescription", SqlDbType.VarChar, 64);
            descriptionParam.Value = this.Description;

            string query = "INSERT INTO items (item_id, item_template_id, item_name, item_description, " +
            "player_hp, player_mp, player_sp, stat_ac, stat_str, stat_sta, stat_dex, stat_int, " +
            "res_fire, res_water, res_spirit, res_air, res_earth, weapon_damage, item_value, " +
            "graphic_tile, graphic_equip, graphic_r, graphic_g, graphic_b, graphic_a, stat_multiplier, " +
            "bound, body_state) VALUES (" +
            this.ItemID + "," +
            this.TemplateID + ", " +
            "@itemName, " +
            "@itemDescription, " +
            this.BaseStats.HP + ", " +
            this.BaseStats.MP + ", " +
            this.BaseStats.SP + ", " +
            this.BaseStats.AC + ", " +
            this.BaseStats.Strength + ", " +
            this.BaseStats.Stamina + ", " +
            this.BaseStats.Dexterity + ", " +
            this.BaseStats.Intelligence + ", " +
            this.BaseStats.FireResist + ", " +
            this.BaseStats.WaterResist + ", " +
            this.BaseStats.SpiritResist + ", " +
            this.BaseStats.AirResist + ", " +
            this.BaseStats.EarthResist + ", " +
            this.weapondamage + ", " +
            this.Value + ", " +
            this.GraphicTile + ", " +
            this.GraphicEquipped + ", " +
            this.GraphicR + ", " +
            this.GraphicG + ", " +
            this.GraphicB + ", " +
            this.GraphicA + ", " +
            this.StatMultiplier + ", " +
            (this.bound ? "'1'" : "'0'") + ", " +
            this.BodyState + ")";

            this.Dirty = false;

            this.Unsaved = false;

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, world.SqlConnection);
            command.Parameters.Add(nameParam);
            command.Parameters.Add(descriptionParam);
            command.BeginExecuteNonQuery(new AsyncCallback(GameWorld.DefaultEndExecuteNonQueryAsyncCallback), command);
        }

        /**
         * SaveItem, updates item info in database
         * 
         */
        public void SaveItem(GameWorld world)
        {
            SqlParameter nameParam = new SqlParameter("@itemName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 64);
            nameParam.Value = this.Name;
            SqlParameter descriptionParam = new SqlParameter("@itemDescription", SqlDbType.VarChar, 64);
            descriptionParam.Value = this.Description;

            string query = "UPDATE items SET " +
                "item_template_id=" + this.TemplateID + ", " +
                "item_name=" + "@itemName, " +
                "item_description=" + "@itemDescription, " + 
                "player_hp=" + this.BaseStats.HP + ", " +
                "player_mp=" + this.BaseStats.MP + ", " +
                "player_sp=" + this.BaseStats.SP + ", " +
                "stat_ac=" + this.BaseStats.AC + ", " +
                "stat_str=" + this.BaseStats.Strength + ", " +
                "stat_sta=" + this.BaseStats.Stamina + ", " +
                "stat_dex=" + this.BaseStats.Dexterity + ", " +
                "stat_int=" + this.BaseStats.Intelligence + ", " + 
                "res_fire=" + this.BaseStats.FireResist + ", " +
                "res_water=" + this.BaseStats.WaterResist + ", " +
                "res_spirit=" + this.BaseStats.SpiritResist + ", " +
                "res_air=" + this.BaseStats.AirResist + ", " +
                "res_earth=" + this.BaseStats.EarthResist + ", " +
                "weapon_damage=" + this.weapondamage + ", " +
                "item_value=" + this.Value + ", " + 
                "graphic_tile=" + this.GraphicTile + ", " +
                "graphic_equip=" + this.GraphicEquipped + ", " +
                "graphic_r=" + this.GraphicR + ", " +
                "graphic_g=" + this.GraphicG + ", " +
                "graphic_b=" + this.GraphicB + ", " +
                "graphic_a=" + this.GraphicA + ", " +
                "stat_multiplier=" + this.StatMultiplier + ", " +
                "bound=" + (this.bound ? "'1'" : "'0'") + ", " +
                "body_state=" + this.BodyState + 
                " WHERE item_id=" + this.ItemID;

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, world.SqlConnection);
            command.Parameters.Add(nameParam);
            command.Parameters.Add(descriptionParam);
            command.BeginExecuteNonQuery(new AsyncCallback(GameWorld.DefaultEndExecuteNonQueryAsyncCallback), command);
            this.Dirty = false;
        }

        /**
         * DeleteItem, deletes item from database
         * 
         */
        public void DeleteItem(GameWorld world)
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
                "DELETE FROM items WHERE item_id=" + this.ItemID, 
                world.SqlConnection);
            command.BeginExecuteNonQuery(new AsyncCallback(GameWorld.DefaultEndExecuteNonQueryAsyncCallback), command);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you define a column as identity the values are generated automatically and you can't insert values unless the setting `identity_insert` is set to on. My guess is that the error is in the insert statement at `string query = "INSERT INTO items (item_id` and that item_id is an identity column, which means you shouldn't insert an explicit value into it but rather do `string query = "INSERT INTO items ( item_template_id, ...)` etc

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 1):

```
   public void AddItem(GameWorld world)
    {
        SqlParameter nameParam = new SqlParameter("@itemName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 64);
        nameParam.Value = this.Name;
        SqlParameter descriptionParam = new SqlParameter("@itemDescription", SqlDbType.VarChar, 64);
        descriptionParam.Value = this.Description;

        string query = "INSERT INTO items (item_template_id, item_name, item_description, " +
        "player_hp, player_mp, player_sp, stat_ac, stat_str, stat_sta, stat_dex, stat_int, " +
        "res_fire, res_water, res_spirit, res_air, res_earth, weapon_damage, item_value, " +
        "graphic_tile, graphic_equip, graphic_r, graphic_g, graphic_b, graphic_a, stat_multiplier, " +
        "bound, body_state) VALUES (" +
        this.TemplateID + ", " +
        "@itemName, " +
        "@itemDescription, " +
        this.BaseStats.HP + ", " +
        this.BaseStats.MP + ", " +
        this.BaseStats.SP + ", " +
        this.BaseStats.AC + ", " +
        this.BaseStats.Strength + ", " +
        this.BaseStats.Stamina + ", " +
        this.BaseStats.Dexterity + ", " +
        this.BaseStats.Intelligence + ", " +
        this.BaseStats.FireResist + ", " +
        this.BaseStats.WaterResist + ", " +
        this.BaseStats.SpiritResist + ", " +
        this.BaseStats.AirResist + ", " +
        this.BaseStats.EarthResist + ", " +
        this.weapondamage + ", " +
        this.Value + ", " +
        this.GraphicTile + ", " +
        this.GraphicEquipped + ", " +
        this.GraphicR + ", " +
        this.GraphicG + ", " +
        this.GraphicB + ", " +
        this.GraphicA + ", " +
        this.StatMultiplier + ", " +
        (this.bound ? "'1'" : "'0'") + ", " +
        this.BodyState + ")";

        this.Dirty = false;

        this.Unsaved = false;

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, world.SqlConnection);
        command.Parameters.Add(nameParam);
        command.Parameters.Add(descriptionParam);
        command.BeginExecuteNonQuery(new AsyncCallback(GameWorld.DefaultEndExecuteNonQueryAsyncCallback), command);
    }
```

dont insert column item_id because it is identity and it will be inserted automatically